# By picture that is displayed in Jupyter notebook isn't shown when running the same code in IDE?

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, pytorch

I was trying to run code from an online tutorial on my local machine by copying code from Jupiter notebook to my IDE (pycharm).

This part

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
from PIL import Image
from torchvision import transforms
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pig_img = Image.open("pig.jpg")
preprocess = transforms.Compose([
   transforms.Resize(224),
   transforms.ToTensor(),
])
pig_tensor = preprocess(pig_img)[None,:,:,:]

plt.imshow(pig_tensor[0].numpy().transpose(1,2,0))
```

While Jupiter notebook shows the imagine - I cannot get it displayed when running in terminal or IDE.

Any ideas why?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `.show()` explicitly to show the image in terminal i.e.

Add this to the end of the code

```
plt.show()
```

From the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.show.html):

> Display a figure. When running in ipython with its pylab mode, display all figures and return to the ipython prompt.
>
> In non-interactive mode, display all figures and block until the figures have been closed; in interactive mode it has no effect unless figures were created prior to a change from non-interactive to interactive mode (not recommended). In that case it displays the figures but does not block.